# Rolling back a question affected the body correctly but missed the title

Tags: bug, rollbacks

I just rolled back [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45504393/solved-simpledateformat-returning-null-but-can-print-date-on-screen) from rev 3 to rev 2 (so the latest version is 4).

In [revision 3](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45504393/revisions), you can see that the body and the title were modified, to add a solution and to mark the title as "solved". However, when I rolled back, the body was reverted and the title was not.

Is this a bug?

I am using Firefox 54.0 on GNU/Linux Mint.

Comment: Revision 3 looks like an "edit and approve" on Revision 2 which may be relevant.

Comment: @MartinSmith Yes, there was another Meta question recently that saw that rolling back an edit when there is an Improve Edit does cause odd behavior.

Comment: @BSMP: I've no feelings either way about whether this is a dup, but thanks for finding that. Ideally we'd get a developer to look at either of them to confirm whether in their opinion this is a bug, and if dev time can be committed.

Comment: @TinyGiant I don't see any thing in that question that says the bug is fixed?

Comment: Yeah, normally fixed Meta posts are re-tagged as 'status-completed' or something like that.

Comment: Oh snap, my bad. For some reason I thoight it was. Nevermind me. @MartinSmith